# <multipart-config> <max-file-size> is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I am trying to restrict the size of file being uploaded via a controller. This app uses web.xml for servlet configuration. This app uses Spring 4.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appname</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <multipart-config>
        <max-file-size>10000</max-file-size>
        <max-request-size>10000</max-request-size>
    </multipart-config>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/appname.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appname</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is not working:

```
<multipart-config>
        <max-file-size>10000</max-file-size>
        <max-request-size>10000</max-request-size>
</multipart-config>
```

I am able to upload files bigger than 10 kb and it is coming to my controller.
Why `<multipart-config>` is not working? Is there more configuration required?

Answer (score 0):

Max-file-size takes values as bytes, you have to multiply for example 500Mo by 1024 * 1024 like below.

```
 <multipart-config>
    <max-file-size>524288000</max-file-size>
    <max-request-size>524288000</max-request-size>
    <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```

You can also remove the annotation on web.xml and add the annotation:

```
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 1024*1024*5)
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Did you even read the question?